# Pandas - mapping between dataframes when set_index can't be used

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe, `df_players`, where player id occurs many times throught many rounds and is thus repeated:

```
       player_id    player_name   position          team      round  player_points
0          74159  Abel Hernández  forward  Internacional         30          -0.1
1          74159  Abel Hernández  forward  Internacional         17           4.0
2          74159  Abel Hernández  forward  Internacional         18          11.0
3          74159  Abel Hernández  forward  Internacional         19          -0.4
4          74159  Abel Hernández  forward  Internacional         20           5.7
...
```

Also I have this `df_teams`:

```
            team    team_points     round
0    Internacional         69.4        30
1    Internacional         10.1        17
2    Internacional         24.3        20
3    Internacional         16.5        18
4    Internacional         33.5        19
...
```

And I need to bring 'team_points' value for each 'round' from `df_teams` into `df_players`, ending up with:

```
       player_id    player_name   position          team      round  player_points  team_points
0          74159  Abel Hernández  forward  Internacional         30          -0.1     69.4
1          74159  Abel Hernández  forward  Internacional         17           4.0     10.1
2          74159  Abel Hernández  forward  Internacional         18          11.0     16.5
3          74159  Abel Hernández  forward  Internacional         19          -0.4     33.5
4          74159  Abel Hernández  forward  Internacional         20           5.7     24.3
```

---

I have tried mapping with:

```
df_players['team_points'] = df_players['round'].map(df_teams.set_index('round')['team_points'])
```

But this throws the error:

```
pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

---

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Try merge on ['team', 'round'] ?

Comment: the complete line of code, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) like this:

```
df_players.merge(df_teams, on=['team', 'round'])
```

This performs an 'inner' join by default to merge only those appear in both tables on the 2 merge fields ['team', 'round'].

Input:  df_players (added a new player at the end):

```
       player_id    player_name   position          team      round  player_points
0          74159  Abel_Hernández  forward  Internacional         30          -0.1
1          74159  Abel_Hernández  forward  Internacional         17           4.0
2          74159  Abel_Hernández  forward  Internacional         18          11.0
3          74159  Abel_Hernández  forward  Internacional         19          -0.4
4          74159  Abel_Hernández  forward  Internacional         20           5.7
5          74160  John_Hernández  forward  Internacional         18           7.7
```

Output:

```
   player_id     player_name position           team  round  player_points  team_points
0      74159  Abel_Hernández  forward  Internacional     30           -0.1         69.4
1      74159  Abel_Hernández  forward  Internacional     17            4.0         10.1
2      74159  Abel_Hernández  forward  Internacional     18           11.0         16.5
3      74160  John_Hernández  forward  Internacional     18            7.7         16.5
4      74159  Abel_Hernández  forward  Internacional     19           -0.4         33.5
5      74159  Abel_Hernández  forward  Internacional     20            5.7         24.3
```

Comment: The output on player_id is a little bit distorted for I copied your data since it has 2 words. Let me fix it

Comment: I added a new player_id 74160 just to test it works for more than one player.  It now appears together with round 18.  You can further sort by player_id if you like.